# Why shell command work in my GitBash but same is not working in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a shell program which like below is working fine in my local machine GitBash command line. But when i execute the same in linux its not working.

I have a template file it have content like below. I have to replace SUBJECT with value passed to my Shell program.
template

```
{

"subject" : "SUBJECT"
"data": {
   "content": "SUBJECT"

}

}
```

My Shell code

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "subject value"$1

sed -i "s/SUBJECT/$1/g" template
```

This code is not working as expected in linux but same as working fine in GitBash.

Comment: What happens when you try to run your script on Linux?

Comment: @Kusalananda Its not giving expected result looks like script is exiting in that line.I dont have server logs. If I comment that line script is working fine.

Comment: Is your Linux shell Bash? What is the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: Do you get an error message when executing the `sed` command directly with inserting your `$1` value

Comment: sed does not support a -i option, is that your problem?